# compare two values running in each loop jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am storing colon separated values in the data attributes of html elements

```
<a class='te' data-tes='test123;123test;234test'>test</a>
<a class='te' data-tes='t3;1st;123test'>test1</a>
```

I would like a function that returns the common values. In the example above only `123test` would match. So far this is what I have tried

```
$('.te').each(function(){
    if($(this).data('tes')!= undefined){
        # Here how can i perform the comparision.
    }
})
```

Comment: What's the question/problem?

Comment: What kind of comparison?

Comment: worksforme http://jsfiddle.net/gSKqb/

Comment: The question is that OP wants to see which values in the data-tes attribute would match between the elements

Comment: Could you please check my answer, and see if it was the solution you were looking for? If it was, please mark my answer as accepted, so that others can see that this question is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by first creating an array that stores each of the data-attributes, split at the `;`

```
var arr = [];
$('.te').each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).data('tes').split(';'));
});
```

This will in your example create an array like this:

```
[
    ["test123", "123test", "234test"],
    ["t3", "1st", "123test"]
]
```

After that, you'll have to run a loop through each of those values to compare them:

```
for (var i=0;i<arr[0].length;i++) {
    if (arr[0][i] == arr[1][i]) {
        //This will only run when the first element's data-tes attribute's value is equal to the second element's. In this case, that'll be for the third value - at i==2.
    }
}
```

Comment: @EditmeHere the problem in that JSFiddle is that your selector doesn't close its string correctly. [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3mRTL/1/) should work.

Comment: @EditmeHere well, the format of this list of elements seems to be quite different from the example code you gave me. Will the page always look like this jsfiddle, or might there be more than 2 *selected* elements?

Comment: As of now only 2 but in future it may increase.

Comment: @EditmeHere is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3mRTL/4/) what you wanted it to do? It now alerts the amount of items that match the colour's listed data-sku values.

Comment: Check in my fiddle If i click the attribute two alert are coming. The second alert value is the right one. But why I am getting the first alert

Comment: Because you changed the condition of the `if` statement to `attr[i] == attr[i]`. You're comparing 2 identical items. Here, try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mRTL/5/), it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
var results = {};

$( ".te" ).each( function( ) {

    var parts = $(this).data( 'tes' ).split( ";" );

    // in case the same string is present twice in
    // same element and nowhere else
    var added = {};

    for( var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++ ) {

        // this string is not in results yet
        if( results[ parts[i] ] == undefined ) {
            results[ parts[i] ] = 1;
            added[ parts[i] ] = 1;
        } // it is in results & if not already present in this string then add
        else if( !added[ parts[i] ] ) {
            results[ parts[i] ]++;
            // record that string is found in this element
            added[ parts[i] ] = 1;
        }
    }

});
```

For your example this produces

```
{"test123":1,"123test":2,"234test":1,"t3":1,"1st":1}
```

Those items whose value is 2 or more are the ones that occur in at least 2 elements. If your requirement is that it exists in all elements then the value must match the number of elements.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D42a8/)